# What's it called when I define a subclass just to abstract away the details of the base class's constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, subclass, copy-constructor

I'm writing a library that provides the ability for two clients to communicate using  ZeroMQ PUB/SUB sockets. Each client application instantiates either a broadcaster endpoint or a receiver endpoint, and those endpoint classes have a Connection member:

```
class Connection {
    Connection(const char* address, int outgoingPort, int incomingPort);
};
```

A Connection has a couple of sockets and is configured to connect to the given address over the respective ports. However, I don't care to expose these details in the classes where the Connection is actually instantiated. The base connection object has a incoming port and an outgoing port, but this detail doesn't need to seep through the rest of the program. In those higher-level layers, it'd be more sensible to think in terms of two designated ports, the data port and the control port. So I have two subclasses which implement constructors to define which port is the incoming port, and which is the outgoing port for that particular type of connection.

```
class BroadcasterConnection : public Connection {
    BroadcasterConnection(int dataPort, int controlPort)
    :Connection("*", dataPort, controlPort) {}
};
class ReceiverConnection : public Connection {
    ReceiverConnection(const char* hostAddress, int dataPort, int controlPort)
    :Connection(hostAddress, controlPort, dataPort) {}
};
```

Additionally, the broadcaster binds to its ports as a stable endpoint, so it needs to use `"*"` in lieu of an actual remote address. Again, classes that instantiate and use a broadcaster connection should not need to concern themselves with this detail, so the BroadcasterConnection constructor takes care of it.

As another example, I do the same thing with the classes that wrap ZeroMQ sockets. I have a base Socket class, and the subclass constructors simply pass the appropriate value (ZMQ_PUB or ZMQ_SUB) from the ZeroMQ headers to the underlying socket. Since we can't have clients using values from ZeroMQ directly, we need to codify the distinction between a PUB socket and a SUB socket in some formal way, and providing a single subclass constructor seemed like a transparent and sensible way of doing that.

```
class Socket:
    Socket(void* context, const char* address, int port, int socketType);

class PublishSocket : public Socket:
    PublishSocket(void* context, const char* address, int port)
    :Socket(context, address, port, ZMQ_PUB) {}

class SubscribeSocket : public Socket:
    SubscribeSocket(void* context, const char* address, int port)
    :Socket(context, address, port, ZMQ_SUB) {}
```

These subclasses don't do anything fancy at all, but I hope you'll agree that they're a useful and healthy addition in the service of abstraction. But I'm not aware of a common name for this simple idiom. When I define a subclass that *only* implements a constructor, solely for the purpose of constructing an object with a more specialized set of parameters, what am I doing?

The key point here is that these subclasses *do not define any additional methods or data*. Here's another example, where there's a base Tag class that identifies any entity of any type. The subclasses are used to create tags for individual types of entities based on some domain-specific parameters, but they all boil down to Tag objects in the end.

```
Tag(char typeIdentifier, int entityIdentifier);

LightTag(int lightIndex):Tag('L', lightIndex) {}
SkeletonTag(const char* skeletonName):Tag('S', hash(skeletonName)) {}
CameraTag():Tag('C', 0) {}
```

So, a few questions:

1. Is there a commonly-used, Googleable name for this idiom?
2. If I write `Connection c = BroadcasterConnection(40001, 40002);`, the copy constructor is invoked. Since `BroadcasterConnection` doesn't define any additional data, the two classes should be interchangeable (RTTI notwithstanding), and we should be able to downcast without any worries of object slicing, right? Is there a similarly convenient syntax for constructing objects in this way that avoids the copy? This seems to happen even in constructor initializer lists.
3. This is a less practical example, but suppose I write `Connection* c = new BroadcasterConnection(40001, 40002);` and then `delete c;`. Connection doesn't have a virtual destructor, but it doesn't have any virtual functions to begin with (so no vtable). Since BroadcasterConnection is a direct subclass of Connection that defines no additional data, would this operation be safe? What if BroadcasterConnection added some member data? Would it then cause memory leaks?
4. Is there any way to explicitly codify the fact that a particular subclass is constructor-only in the way described above, so that the compiler won't allow it to contain any additional data?

And, of course, if there's a fundamentally better way of solving the same problem, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful.  You invoked undefined behavior.

**5.3.5**

> 3) In the first alternative (delete object ), if the static type of the operand is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the operand’s dynamic type and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined. [...]

I suspect that it will almost always work, but you are invoking undefined behavior, and as such asked the compiler to email the contents of your hard drive to a photo printer, and use your credit card to pay for it.  Or whatever else it feels like.

In practice, it will probably just call the base class destructor.

Note that most of the above utility can be handled via functions that return copies of base class objects with the names of the derived classes.  Ie, instead of a class called SubscribeSocket, you have a function called `SubscribeSocket` that returns a `Socket`.  Between move semantics (you do have a fast move on `Socket`, right?) and RVO (assuming you are willing to expose the implementation of `SubscribeSocket`), this will be efficient.

One advantage your scheme has is that you can type your `Socket`s if required.  An approach that works which doesn't invoke undefined behavior (but does have a few quirks) is to define a `SubscribeSocket` class that is unrelated to `Socket`, which owns a `Socket`, forwards its constructor to it, and has `operator Socket&()` and `operator Socket const&() const`, allowing it to be passed to an API that requires `Sockets`.  Throw in a `.GetSocket()` method for when you need it explicitly.  Avoid `operator=(Socket const&)` and you now block slicing.  Maybe have an explicit "create-from-socket" type function that does checks in debug...